# Copy entire sheet as it is viewed, without hidden rows

Tags: excel, copy, visible, vba

I have a code that I'm using to copy an entire sheet from another workbook, That sheet that I want to copy has hidden columns that is also copied with that code I'm using at the moment.

So i want to copy the sheet exactly how its viewed. without the hidden columns and so on.

This is the code i have at the moment.

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant
Set y = ThisWorkbook
Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Delete

Set x = Workbooks.Open("http://blabla/download.xlsx")



With x.Sheets("SME Tal").UsedRange
    y.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
```

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) of the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) (with [xlCellTypeVisible property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx)).

```
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant
Dim a As Long

Set y = ThisWorkbook
y.Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Delete

Set x = Workbooks.Open("http://blabla/download.xlsx")

With x.Sheets("SME Tal").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For a = 1 To .Areas.Count
        With .Areas(a)
            y.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Resize( _
                .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Offset( _
                    0, Application.CountA(y.Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(1))) = .Value
        End With
    Next a
End With
```

The .Areas could be further broken into discontiguous ranges if you had hidden rows. More pre-algebra maths would be needed to offset down as well as right.

I'm not sure why you decided to work with [Workbook Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) and not [Worksheet Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).